# [imodel.js]I am using imodel.js front-end to create my own geometric model, and encountered a problem when displaying it

Tags: javascript, typescript, imodeljs

I used imodel.js front-end to create a geometric model of my own, which contains a collection element, such as a box. I put the model in the SpatialViewState that already exists in bim, and I cannot display my model in the current view. Then I created my own SpatialViewState, but it can display my own model. May I ask, why is this happening? Also, if I modify the ModelSelectorState in SpatialViewState through imodel.js front-end, can it be persisted to the cloud? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements and models are created on the back-end, not the front-end. Are you trying to create a new persistent model containing some elements? Or do you just want to be able to draw some geometry (like your box) in the viewport? In the latter case, you probably want to use a [decorator](https://www.imodeljs.org/learning/frontend/viewdecorations/).

FYI iModel.js now has a [discussions page](https://github.com/imodeljs/imodeljs/discussions) on github, which you might find a little more conducive to discussion.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me a lot.